# How do I NOT send an empty form field via email with a PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML order form with approx 100 possible entries.  The form posts to a PHP file.  The PHP file send an email with the order quantities and $totals per item.
The problem is that it sends the info when the quantity = 0 - which, of course, makes the resulting email quite cumbersome.
SO, my question is: How do I NOT send the info when the quantity is 0

Here is an example of the coding I have for the POST portion:

```
if( !empty($_POST[""]) )
else
{
    $qtyG01lg = 0;
    $totalG01lg = 0;
}
```

And here is the part I do NOT want to send if the quantity is "0":

```
$body .= "     G01-large: (" . $qtyG01lg . " @ $10.00ea) = " . $totalG01lg . "\n";
```

Comment: Post your complete handling code

Comment: I would use sizeof($_POST) rather than !empty.

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['elementName']) || (int) $_POST['elementName'] == 0) {
// Code
}`

Comment: the complete code is at  http://barefoot-contessa-art.com/ordering/process-08.txt - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines for checking if the quantity is 0 set should be,

```
 if( $qtyG01lg > 0 && $totalG01lg > 0 )
  $body .= "     G01-large: (" . $qtyG01lg . " @ $10.00ea) = " . $totalG01lg . "\n";
```

Also, you cannot have an empty string as the name/key in $_POST (`if( !empty($_POST[""]) )`). So, the line should be,

```
 if( !empty($_POST) ) //or specify the key/index for quantity or whatever you want to check
```

Answer (score 0):

something like perhaps:

```
if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST['quantity']))
```

could you supply a little more code?

Comment: Here's the complete PHP code (As you can see it's a work in progress - I'm sure there's a way to 'compress' this, but I'm attacking one issue at a time :)

Comment: wups - here's the URL  [link] (http://barefoot-contessa-art.com/ordering/process-08.txt)

Comment: line 199 to line 204 .. your missing some dollar signs .. G011g, etc
line 208, add: if($GrantTotal>0){
line 253, add: }

that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST && $_POST["quantity"]>0)
  $body .= "     G01-large: (" . $qtyG01lg . " @ $10.00ea) = " . $totalG01lg . "\n";
```

Comment: Running `if` on variables that may or may not even exist is bad practice. Use `isset()`.